# How to visualize norm 3, norm 4,.. distance between two points in X-Y Plane

Tags: statistics, plane-geometry

Distance between Two points can be expressed as

$(|x_1 - x_2|^m + |y_1 - y_2|^m)^{\frac{1}{m}}$

$m = 1$ `1 norm distance` (Manhattan Distance)

[image]

$m = 2$ `2 norm distance` (Euclidean Distance)

[image]

How can I visualize `3 norm`, `4 norm`,... distance. I searched internet and all I could find is the comparison of `1 norm` and `2 norm`. I couldn't be able to find the visualization of `3 norm`, `4 norm`, ... distance. Can anybody help me to visualizes these distances.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a picture for you:
$$\color{blue}{‖x‖_1 = 1} \quad ‖x‖_2 = 1 \quad \color{orange}{‖x‖_5 = 1}  \quad \color{red}{‖x‖_∞ = 1}$$
[image]

(It is sufficient to consider the unit balls centered at 0 because it "doesn't matter" where the centre is.) To understand this diagram, pick any point on the corresponding ball; that point is of $p$-distance $1$ from $0$.

As far as I know, the $p$-norms for $p=1,2,∞$ are the only cases that have a clear interpretation. Everything else is an 'interpolation' in between; if $p≈ 1$, then its the $1$-norm, but fudged slightly. If $p\gg 1$ then its like the $∞$-norm. As you can see, $p=5$ is already pretty close to the $∞$-norm.

Comment: $||x||_2$ is Euclidean Distance. So I think It would be Blue figure rather Black figure.

Comment: @Atinesh well the black one is a circle, which should be the 2 norm. The blue one is a diamond; thats the 1-norm ball.

Comment: I'm confused as far as I know Euclidean distance can be calculated using `Pythagoras theorem`. How can we apply that theorem in case of Curve.

Comment: @Atinesh Sorry, but what do you mean? Euclidean distance is defined to be $‖x-y‖_2 := \sqrt{|x_1 - x_2|^2 + |y_1 - y_2|^2}$. This is a definition, not a theorem.

Comment: Please see this
http://s27.postimg.org/ufsb392cz/Untitled.png

Comment: The Pythagorean theorem expresses the length of the diagonal as a function of the side lengths of a right triangle. The fact that you see a ball when you use the 2-norm is explained by this theorem. But the 2-norm can always be calculated by its defining formula, see above. In addition, there is no 'pythagorean theorem' for any other norm(which provides geometric intuition) but you can always calculate the p-norm with its definition.

Comment: @Atinesh sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: can someone help me with graphing for $max(|x_1|,|x_2|)$

Comment: @SyedMuhammadAsad ask a new question, comments are bad for this

Answer (score 1):

You could try plotting the unit sphere of these norms, i.e. the set of points at an $m$-distance 1 from the origin. Plot the curve for several different values of $m$ between 1 and infinity. You will see that the unit balls are nested within each other. The diamond of the $m=1$ ball "morphs" into the familiar Euclidean ball, and out the other side, where it morphs into the $m = \infty$ ball. These shapes interpolate between the extremes, the Euclidean ball being a kind of half-way point. To learn more about this spectrum of $m$s, with $m=2$ as a kind of midpoint between 1 and $\infty$, you could read about $L_p$ spaces in books on measure theory and functional analysis, and Banach space theory. In particular you could learn about how every $m$, which I am calling $p$, between 1 and 2 has a "twin" called $q$ which is between 2 and $\infty$, and $p$ and $q$ are so-called Holder conjugates, related by $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$. To understand the relationship between the unit balls and the distances between points, center a copy of the unit ball at $X$, and shrink or expand it until it touches $Y$. See also "Minkowski functional" or "Gauge".

Another instructive exercise would be to plot the "unit sphere" for values of $m$ between 0 and 1, for instance, $m=\frac{1}{2}$. What do you notice is different about such spheres ? Why does this make them unsuitable for measuring distance ? Hint: Consider the norm of the sum of two vectors.

Comment: Can you explain with any diagrams, It'll be more clear to me.

Comment: By all means: http://wolfr.am/7FnAWmux, http://wolfr.am/7FnBT71Y, http://wolfr.am/7FnCCAXz, http://wolfr.am/7FnDpZr1, http://wolfr.am/7FnEb5SA, http://wolfr.am/7FnF4XeX